# Restrict translation and editing of node to one language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

## Edit

I found this in Workbench Access issue queue:
https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access/issues/2982941#comment-12670744

It seems as if I need to deactivate the `translate *bundle* *node*` permissions, because if those are set, the permission will be short circuited and no other access restrictions may apply, and create a hole bunch of new `*translate *bundle* *node* *language*` permissions on my own. In my case we have 15 node types and 6 languages. That would result in 90 new permissions. That is overwhelming.

## Original Question

I'm trying to restrict the access to creating and editing of nodes in the Drupal admin section to only one language for a user. I didn't find a module which provides for this feature. **Is there any module that does this?**

I then tried to create my own module. I came up with this solution

#### File: custom_i18n_access.module

```
<?php

use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;


/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 *
 * Prevent editor role to edit and/or delete fr/en nodes. Quick and dirty.
 */
function custom_i18n_access_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account)
{

    $roles = $account->getRoles();

    if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
    }

    if ($op !== 'update' && $op !== 'delete') {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
    }

    // Access should be restricted only if this permission is set
    if (!$account->hasPermission('custom_i18n_access_restrict')) {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
    }
    
    $current_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
    $lang             = $current_language->getId();

    if ($account->hasPermission("custom_i18n_access_{$lang}_allow")) {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
}
```

#### File: custom_i18n_access.permissions.yml

```
permission_callbacks:
  - Drupal\custom_i18n_access\Permissions::permissions
```

#### File: src/Permissions.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_i18n_access;

class Permissions {
    public function permissions() {
        $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();

        $permissions["custom_i18n_access_restrict"] = [
            'title' => t("Restrict language access"),
            'description' => 'Restrict the edit access of nodes',
        ];

        foreach($languages as $lang) {
            $permissions["custom_i18n_access_{$lang->getId()}_allow"] = [
                'title' => t("Allow to edit @lang content", ['@lang' => $lang->getName()]),
            ];
        }

        return $permissions;
    }
}
```

This custom module successfully restricts the editing and deleting of **existing** content to only the language I specified in the permissions. But it does not prevent **new** translations of the content into  other languages.

As I see it, the `HOOK_node_access` hook is not called for every language when on the translations subtask page. How can I achieve this? **Is there a different hook for that?** I didn't find any help online.

Comment: Not sure if feasible, but you can restrict language for users https://www.drupal.org/project/language_access

Comment: @ales I think this is for view. I need edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest here checking NodeTranslationHandler class, in entityFormAlter you could find a way how to restrict a user from creating a new translation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Basically, each entity type is using their own translation handler ContentTranslationHandler, you could try to even override this handler using hook_entity_type_alter() f.e.                                                                                           `/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->setHandlerClass('translation', CustomTranslationHandler::class);
}`